# Investigate failures in elasticache redis seeding

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm creating a new Elasticache redis cluster with a 2gb seed file created from an on-premise redis instance using a process documented in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-seeding-redis.html). For some reason the process fails after some time with status marked as "restore-failed", showing the following in the web console:

[image]

I've checked that the chosen node type contains enough memory and the chosen redis version matches the original. Is there an option to see the logs somehow or to investigate further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information was visible in the ElastiCache "Events" page and in my case the problem was caused by insufficient permissions of the seeded file.

[image]